# How do I make this UITableView clear (transparent) in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

How do I make this `UITableView` and it's cells clear in Swift 3.

I have gone through the previous threads but I am still getting a white background.

As you can see from my code I have tried the various methods mentioned:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    self.communitiesTableView.delegate = self
    self.communitiesTableView.dataSource = self

    let background = CAGradientLayer().bespokeColor()
    background.frame = self.view.bounds
  //      view.addSubview(background)
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

and in my cell table function:

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let title = self.communities[indexPath.row]
    let cell = UITableViewCell()


    cell.textLabel?.text = title
    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 12)
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.red
    cell.textLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear


    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    communitiesTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    cell.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

    return cell

}
```

This gif shows the problem - notice the black lines showing the table is present just not populated (as no-one is logged in)

But for a second it is clear, then turns white.
Where am I going wrong?

This is from another post that I have found:

Apple document says

... In iOS 7, cells have a white background by default; in earlier versions of iOS, cells inherit the background color of the enclosing table view. If you want to change the background color of a cell, do so in the tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: method of your table view delegate.

You might need to use willDisplayCell UITableView delegate method to have a transparent background for your table view .

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cellforRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
  [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
}
```

How do I apply the code above as it says its for iOS 7?

Comment: Code looks good. For debug, set `cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear`. If the issue persists, there is another view involved.  In this case, show how the view and the cell is stacked in storyboard. This: `cell.isOpaque = false`is not needed, the views alpha has nothing to do with your issue.

Comment: The issue has remained after adding peoples suggestions.  I have updated the code to reflect this.  The table is contained within a StackView.  If I remove the table from this StackView, the problem remains...

Comment: I have take the Table out of the StackView though and the problem persists.

Comment: Try once `cell.backgroundColor = .clear` in `cellForRowAt indexPath`.
`

Comment: It's clear for about a second, and the it goes white

Comment: @RDowns try comment this line `self.view.layer.insertSublayer(background, at: 0)` and check is it working?

Comment: What is the output you are getting out of this code? and what is expected result? You may add the images here.

Comment: @RDowns Try to initialised cell like this `let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, 
reuseIdentifier: "Cell")`

Comment: same! ??? it's getting annoying now!

Comment: @RDowns Problem may be with this line `self.communitiesTableView.backgroundView = nil` remove this one.

Comment: nope.  Maybe we're all looking in the wrong place - I did read somewhere on an old thread that someone had a similar problem and fixed it by doing something in the delegate. But I couldn't quite work out what they were doing

Comment: check my edit at the bottom and what you mean background moving from clear to  white..are you using animation block anywhere in your code?

Comment: going to try recording a gif to show you

Comment: 1)first thing change your ` cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black` to some other` visible colour`  2)  `self.view.layer.insertSublayer(background, at: 0)` change to `view.addSubview(background)`  3)delete `tableview backgroundColor` setting code from `viewDidLoad`...and try my answer...

Comment: i couldn't do stage 2 as it errored as its relating to an extension so I commented it out.  I did the rest. The problem is still there and I changed the text colour to red which worked. Hang on, just seen your updated code...

Comment: it's currently crashing when I click on communities. Doesn't say why - goes back to Xcode to my appDelegate and Thread 1 : SIGABRT

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128474/discussion-between-joe-and-rdowns).

Comment: Xcode 8.3.2 Swift 3.  This was doing my head in.  Thanks very much for posting.  Worked a treat

Answer (score 55, accepted):

**Note:** Below code been tested in `Swift 3`.

**Method 1:**

Select your tableViewCell from your `storyboard` and goto `Attributes Inspector` under `View` change `Background` to `clear`

**Method 2:** Try below code inside your `cellForRowAt`

```
  cell.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
```

[image]

**Note :** If above method didn't works.try clear your project build by pressing `shift + option + command + k`

**Update:** Update your `cellForRowAt` from below code...

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = communities[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 12)
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.red // set to any colour 
    cell.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the effort.  It didn't work - I think what you've shown here is correct and the problem in this instance must be something around how the table is getting loaded.  As when it first appears it is clear, and then goes white.

Comment: I thought I had already tried this, until I read your answer and realize the color was set do "Default" instead of "Clear color".

Answer (score 15):

You can try this

In **viewDidLoad**:

```
tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

In **cellForRowAt:**

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

It's work for me.

Comment: this worked for me with the addition of - cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

Comment: Thanks @HH887, just with cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear worked for me

Answer (score 10):

The two first answer doesn't work for me so I add a clear background everywhere and the white bg go away.

```
cell.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
cell.backgroundColor = .clear
tableView.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
tableView.backgroundColor = .clear
```

**SWIFT 5.5.3**

Answer (score 8):

You have to set both table and cell background clear.

Inside tableView function:

```
tableView.backgroundColor = .clear
cell.backgroundColor = .clear
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
```

Comment: still no change...strange.

Comment: just added:  tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()  still no luck

Comment: That's weird. Just tested and appears to be working fine for me. Other than recommending cleaning (Shift-Command-K) and restarting I can't really help.

Answer (score 5):

For this to work you have to implement a new tableview method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell,
               forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing setting the background colour of contentView of the cell.

`cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, you can check your table view's alpha.

Comment: Setting the alpha value to zero will _hide_ the complete table view with all subviews. The alpha value influences always the transparency of the subviews.

Comment: This is a useful answer. I have a case where I'm loading a table with data from various core data entities. When the table loads values from a new entity, I want the table to refresh. However, this will not happen if there are no values in a particular data set - cellForRow is not called. Setting the alpha to 0 in the data collection routines, and then to 1 in cellForRow solves the table reset for me. YMMV

Answer (score 1):

Setting these wont be enough as you have not applied `clear color` to the `contentView` of the `tableView` and so it is coloring white in it. Try this in cellForRowAtIndexPath

`cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor .clearColor()`

Comment: there are three things whose color you need to change. 1) TableView's Background, 2) TableView's Cell, 3) TableView Cell's Content VIew and you will acheive a total transparent background unless you are creating anyother thing on the top of the cell.

Comment: There has to be something else we're missing - I've updated my code in the question to show that i've done everything you have mentioned (i believe)

Comment: Just a quick thought, are you trying to clear the color of the tableView but you have set white color to the view behind the tableView and think that tableView's color is not being clear ? not sure, just a thought. May be this could help. @RDowns

Answer (score 1):

Make sure in the Identity Inspector you have Custom Class -> Class "YourCustomClassCellName" selected in the Drop Down Menu. With your UITableViewCell selected in Interface Builder, make sure your Identifier is "YourCellName" and then in the func tableView(_ tableViewL UITableView, cellForRowAt) method before the return cell that you have cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear i.e,

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "YourCellName", for: indexPath) as? YourCellNameClass {
        cell.configureCell(parameter: ClassDataModel[indexPath.row])
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        return cell
    } else {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
```

I had the same issue and wrote all the code before I checked to see make sure my CellClass was selected and face palmed when I spent an hour wondering why it worked on another viewController and not in this instance. Even if you use IB to clear out the default white backgrounds, you still have to write the cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear. I was like yep, I found another bug in 8.2.1, but no just an iD10t operator bug.

Answer (score 1):

**I tested using swift 3. It's working**

```
uiTableName.backgroundView = nil
uiTableName.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

Answer (score 1):

In the Storyboard for the **TableView** and **TableViewCell**, instead of setting the background to "Clear/Default" set the background to white (or any color) with an opacity of 0.

[image]

Also make sure you set the **ContentView** background to clear, but the TableViewCell is what was tripping me up. By doing this you shouldn't need to do anything in the code.

Answer (score 0):

**In Swift 4, Write the following code under viewDidLoad of your desired class:-**

```
tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

**Write the following code under the cellForRowAt i.e dataSource of your tableView:-**

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellIdentifierName", for: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell //Cell ClassName
cell.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
return cell
```

Answer (score 0):

**Why nobody said about this?:**

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
// Drag and drop the tableView from the storyboard

override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()      
   tableView.isHidden = true
}
```

The result gives you an opportunity to hide the whole tableView with a single line.